# Merging Array and removing duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have an array that looks like this

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 1,2,4
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1,2
        [24] => 2
        [44] => 1,2,3,4,5
        [86] => 1,2,5
        [139] => 4
        [156] => 1,4
        [170] => 1,2,4,5
        [201] => 1,3
        [208] => 1,2,3
        [237] => 1,5
    )
```

Now i want to merge all values into one single array without the duplicates so the desired output should look like this

```
Array(
[0]=>1,2,3,4,5
)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is that an array of arrays or an array of strings?

Comment: array values is string

Comment: use implode(), explode(), and array_unique().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version:

```
$result = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', implode(',', $array))));
```

Explanation:

First you need to join all array elements to one string using implode() and "," as divider.

This will have the effect that

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,2,4
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1,2
)
```

will be joined to a string that looks like

```
1,2,4,1,1,2
```

Then you explode the string by using explode() and "," which will split up all elements into a single array value

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 2
)
```

Then you make the values of the array unique by using array_unique() which will give you an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
)
```

At the end you implode them again by using implode() and "," and here is your result as a string:

```
1,2,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
$output = [];
array_map(function ($numbers) use (&$output) {
    $output = array_merge($output, explode(",", $numbers));
}, $input);
$output = array_unique($output);
```